# Cannot connect my node application with mongoDB atlas

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I cannot to connect my application with MongoDB. I tried everything that I found in google but the problem is not solving.

[this is error in console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zlmwQ.png)

[this is my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pcn0l.png)

"express": "^4.17.1",
"mongoose": "^5.9.25"

IP Address
0.0.0.0/0  (includes your current IP address)

Comment: Please add error and code as text, not as image.

Comment: i connect to  your instance OK ... stdout  below :

Comment: rob@ Documents$ mongo "mongodb+srv://blogs.qvygf.mongodb.net/blogNode" --username khan
MongoDB shell version v3.6.18
Enter password:

Comment: Is the server running?

Comment: What do you have in the whitelist of your atlas database? You can check what is it here: https://docs.atlas.mongodb.com/security-whitelist/